# HTML file saved in Google Drive to be parsed into a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a file that comes from the bank in an HTML format. They send this file as a transaction happens and I have a appscript to save the attachment to a Drive folder. I want to parse the HTML and copy the table to a spreadsheet appending it at the bottom.

I have created this piece of code, but XML parsing of HTML is a mystery for me, so It doens't work

```js
    function parseTablesFromHTML() {
      var folderId = "1NrgsTgB3q573wav3cQsse4sAT8poeI77";
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      var htmls = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.HTML); 
      var sheetId = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-mjEUqvy49Wvct13XrWi6TU1dw1VPwesfYJRKJ5T6s/edit#gid=0";
      
        //Set up spreadsheet
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheetId);
      SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
      Logger.log('File name: ' + ss.getName());
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
      var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
      while (htmls.hasNext()) {
      var html = htmls.next().getId();
      var response = DriveApp.getFileById(html).getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var xmlDoc = XmlService.parse(response);
      var b = xmlDoc.getElement().getElement("body");
      var table = b.getElement("div").getElement("div").getElement("div").getElements("div")[1].getElement("table");
      var rows = [];
      var trs = table.getElements("tr");
      for (var r=0,rlength=trs.length; r<rlength; r++) {
        var tds = trs[r].getElements("td");
        var row = [];
        for (var c=0,clength=tds.length; c<clength; c++) {
          row.push(tds[c].getText());
        }
        rows.push(row);
      }
    
      Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(rows));
    
    }
    }
```

the html code looks like this

```html
<table bordercolor="black" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="100%" class="style0" BORDER="1" FRAME="BOX" RULES="NONE">
          <tr>
            <td class="td-header" align="center" width="15%">Process date</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="center" width="5%">Reference</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="center" width="10%">Value date</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="right" width="5%">Amount</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="center" width="5%">Type</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="left" width="40%">Description</td>
            <td class="td-header" align="center" width="25%">details BISERA</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
              <hr size="1" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">02.10.2020 16:13:22</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
              <font color="blue">286B2P12027600HM</font>
            </td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">02.10.2020</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">317.63</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">CT</td>
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">Получен междубанков превод<br /><br />PO F 303<br />.</td>
            <td align="center">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">test iban</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">test</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Considerations

`.getElement()` is **not** a function. I consider this the root cause of your problems since you won't be able to call an nonexistent method.
[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document) is the XmlService's Document Class documentation please refer to it when adjusting the example in this answer to your solution.

### Code snippet

This is how to get the first row's cells text: *(table's headers)*

```
var html = 'the html code you posted in the question';
var parsed = XmlService.parse(html);
Logger.log(
    parsed.getRootElement()
          .getChildren('tr')[0] // Gets the first row (headers)
          .getChildren('td')
          .map(cell => cell.getText())
); //[Process date, Reference, Value date, Amount, Type, Description, details BISERA]
```

### Reference

[XmlService Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document)

[XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

Comment: Hey Alessandro,

Thanks for helping here.
I'm trying your code where I only modified the HTML path and I'm getting a parsing error "Exception: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (line 13, file "Code")"

``` js 
 var html = folder.getFilesByName("2020_10_02_04_26_51_9977.html") ;
  var parsed = XmlService.parse(html);
  Logger.log(
    parsed.getRootElement()
    .getChildren('tr')[0] // Gets the first row (headers)
    .getChildren('td')
    .map(cell => cell.getText())
```